# Norm of the inverse of an M-matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

Let $A$ be an M-matrix: its offdiagonal elements are non-positive and there exists a positive vector $y$ such that $Ay$ is positive.

Do you know any reference for the following inequality?

$$ \|A^{-1}\|_\infty\leq\frac{\|y\|_\infty}{\min_i (Ay)_i}. $$